# How can i change test data in tensorflow?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, predict

Sorry, my English is not very good.

My DNN model has already been trained.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(15,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, epochs=200, validation_split=0.1)
```

and Here is new data,It  is handled as a pipeline.
This data matches the shape of the input data.

```
test_data = [20863, 416326, 709402, 297455, 409472, 318053, 369461, 139100]

def Pipeline(data):
    # Beers Law
    for i in range(0, 7):
        col_name = 'wavelength{}'.format(i+9)
        data.insert(i+8, data[i+1] / data[i])
    # MinMaxScaler
    X_scale = (data - X_min) / (X_max - X_min)
    return X_scale

X = Pipeline(test_data)
model.predict(X)
```

But I tried to prediction, but I get an error.
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_1" (type Sequential).

How can i change test data?

Comment: your data should be of shape `(batch_size, n_features)` but currently, your data is of shape `(n_features,)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reshape the X array, which is a single data point from what I can see, to a [15,1] array?